# Including spark in spring boot project

Tags: spring, scala, apache-spark

I have java spring boot project(for web server), and it works find.
After that, I added spark depencies on this project, and it build without error.

```
In gradle

compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.0.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.0.1'
```

BUT everytime spring web server got request, web server kept re-compiling itself.

```
 some request output 
|------------|------------|-----|------------|

// WHEN REQEUST GOT INTO, SPRING IS CLOSED AND RESTARTED ITSELF. WHY?????

17:26:19.052 INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext [] - [ : ]Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@722b17b0: startup date [Mon Nov 21 17:26:02 KST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
17:26:19.055 INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter [] - [ : ]Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
17:26:19,607 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
17:26:19,607 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SQLFileAppender]
17:26:19,615 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
17:26:19,615 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern log/sql.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
17:26:19,616 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'log/sql.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.
17:26:19,616 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
17:26:19,616 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Mon Nov 21 17:26:19 KST 2016
17:26:19,618 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:26:19,622 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SQLFileAppender] - Active log file name: log/sql.2016-11-21.log
17:26:19,623 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SQLFileAppender] - File property is set to [null]
17:26:19,623 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
17:26:19,623 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [ControllerFileAppender]
17:26:19,623 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
17:26:19,624 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern log/controller.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
17:26:19,624 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'log/controller.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.
17:26:19,624 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
17:26:19,624 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Mon Nov 21 17:26:19 KST 2016
17:26:19,624 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:26:19,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[ControllerFileAppender] - Active log file name: log/controller.2016-11-21.log
17:26:19,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[ControllerFileAppender] - File property is set to [null]
17:26:19,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
17:26:19,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [console]
17:26:19,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
17:26:19,629 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@be00188 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [console] to Logger[ROOT]
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [jdbc] to OFF
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@be00188 - Propagating OFF level on Logger[jdbc] onto the JUL framework
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [jdbc.sqltiming] to INFO
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@be00188 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[jdbc.sqltiming] onto the JUL framework
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SQLFileAppender] to Logger[jdbc.sqltiming]
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [jdbc.resultsettable] to INFO
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@be00188 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[jdbc.resultsettable] onto the JUL framework
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [Controller] to INFO
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@be00188 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[Controller] onto the JUL framework
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [ControllerFileAppender] to Logger[Controller]
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
17:26:19,630 |-INFO in org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator@6917246 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.2.RELEASE)
```

Comment: Could you provide code snippet and info how you use spark in your project ?

Comment: Since this problem came up, I deleted all code related to spark in my project. i just added it on gradle.